# asp mvc core 3 Client side validation for a custom attribute validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a custom validation attribute like so:

```
public class UniqueTitleAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
           object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var context = (MyDBContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(MyDBContext));
            var entity = context.Pages.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Title == value.ToString());

            if (entity != null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(value.ToString()));
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public string GetErrorMessage(string title)
        {
            return $"Title {title} is already in use.";
        }
    }
```

And the in the model:

```
[UniqueTitle]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

And it works great, however I would also like to be able to add client side validation?

Comment: You have to create the custom client-side validation logic as well. This is documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#custom-client-side-validation

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes I am aware of that but I don't really get it honestly Anyway, can you please confirm that my c# code is sufficient? Also, when extending validator, in my case should it be something like: `$.validator.addMethod('uniquetitle'` ?

Comment: What do the docs say? You need to attempt a solution. If you run into issues, *then* we can help you with those. As it stands, it's just "write this code for me", and that's not what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the custom validation attribute, implement the `IClientModelValidator` interface and create an `AddValidation` method. In the `AddValidation` method, add `data-` attributes for validation as follows:

```
public class UniqueTitleAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
       object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var context = (ApplicationDbContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));
        var entity = context.Articles.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Title == value.ToString());

        if (entity != null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(value.ToString()));
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        Type obj = typeof(Article);
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-uniquetitle", GetErrorMessage());
    }
    private bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return false;
        }

        attributes.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"The title is already in use.";
    }
    public string GetErrorMessage(string title)
    {
        return $"Title {title} is already in use.";
    }
}
```

Add a method to jQuery validation library. It uses `addMethod()` method to specify our own validation function. The validation function receives the value entered in the title textbox. It then performs the validation and returns a boolean value.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="post" asp-action="CreateArticle">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Author" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Author" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Author" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var titlelist = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.TitleList));
    $.validator.addMethod("uniquetitle",
    function (value, element, param) {

        if (titlelist.includes(value)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("uniquetitle");
  </script>
}
```

Save the TitleList in ViewBag in the Get method of the view ,in order to judge if the title is in use from js:

```
public IActionResult CreateArticle()
    {
        ViewBag.TitleList = _context.Articles.Select(a => a.Title).ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
You have to use jquery and unobtrusive client side validation so fetch those urls in 
your page.

Use like 
<label asp-for="Name"></label>
<input asp-for="Name"/>
<span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>

Here i have taken example of Name as validation will fire on Name property but you can 
change property on which you want.
```

Comment: I am including those, however for custom validators you need custom js code as well.